# How to display some static data into an ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to display some data in an ExpandableListView.

For 1st position, say

```
name  roll  mark 
a     10    50
b     11   55
c     12   56
```

For the 2nd

```
name  roll  mark 
a     7     5
b     5     5
c     3     5
```

I have made an ArrayAdapter for each field (name, roll, mark) and display this in 3 TextViews.
Because of that, I have to make an ArrayAdapter for rolling the 2 time

Is there any other better option for doing this?

Comment: you can try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html

Comment: case 0:
//    Emg_title.setText(arrayAdapterno.getItem(childPosition).toString());
//    break; any better way
//   case 1:
//    Emg_title.setText(arrayAdapter.getItem(childPosition).toString());
//    break;

Comment: like create one table and take data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined Adapter which will render a HashMap You can create a custom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter.

Here is an example for HashMap in Custom Adapters :

```
public class HashMapAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private HashMap<String, String> mData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    public HashMapAdapter(HashMap<String, String> data){
        mData  = data;
        mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String key = mKeys[pos];
        String Value = getItem(pos).toString();

        //do your view stuff here

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and if you want toggle effect than  you can use [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) in place of simple ArrayAdapter.

[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) you can find out how to use HashMap in ExpandableListAdapter.You can pass your HashMap from Constructor and use it in Adapter.

Comment: how to use haspmap in this ?